# How to change the filter selection in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I'm working with the following example on jsbin (code modified from @oleg's example)

http://jsbin.com/owitod/18/edit

I've got a jquery-ui dialog box which shows a drop down box which mimics the filter drop down for one of the columns and a button. When the button is clicked the alert dialog shows the current jqGrid filters. However, when I change the drop down selection in the drop down inside the dialog box, then I want the jqGrid filters to be changed as well.

Example for above demo:

1. select category sport
2. click show dialog
3. notice sport is preselected
4. click show filters and notice:

   {"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"Category","op":"eq","data":"sport"}]}
5. change drop down in dialog box to science
6. At this point when i click show filters I want the following to be alerted

   {"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"Category","op":"eq","data":"science"}]}

I tried the following in the code but it doesn't work:

```
$("#gs_Category").val($("#mycat").val());  //this doesn't work...

alert(jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData').filters);
```

Comment: Your jsbin example is throwing an error and will not load.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error you are having is with trying to set the selected option.  `gs_Category` is a select dropdown.  To change the option that is selected, you try:

```
$('#gs_Category').find('option[value="' + $('#mycat').val() + '"]').attr('selected', true);
```

**UPDATE**

Adding the following line after setting the selected value will cause the grid's filter event to be triggered (since you are using the local datatype).

```
$('#gs_Category').trigger('change');
```

Comment: Using `attr()` in this way is no longer preferred - use `prop()` instead. See http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: @ChristopherArmstrong My original answer used the `prop` method (and I much prefer using that), however I kept receiving an error saying `.prop` is not a function.  I switched it to `attr`, and it worked fine.

Comment: @ChristopherArmstrong After looking more into the OP's code, the reason `.prop` will not work, is they are using 1.5.  The `.prop` method wasn't available until 1.6.